# Labelling position vectors and proving result thereafter

Tags: vectors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpS8K.png)

How do I label the position vectors & what would be an efficacious way to continue the proof?

Comment: This is a nice question, but if possible, please do not post links to pictures and try (where possible) to explain what you have already tried. Labelling the position vectors OA, OB, OC would be one option to start. From there, since there are perpendicular vectors, consider using the scalar product.